# drupal stuck at admin and getting slow - how to troubleshoot a modules?

Tags: debugging, drupal, module

how do i detect what module causes the whole site to be slow? i recentcly added some new modules and one of them i think causes me problems

Answer (score 3):

The Drupal handbooks have a page on [server tuning considerations](http://drupal.org/node/2601).

Some methods include installing the [Devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) to [track down slow queries](http://www.kinetasystems.com/blog/my-drupal-site-is-slow-what-can-i-do-part-2) or [profile memory usage](http://drupal.org/node/659980). Or you can selectively disable modules, to track down the offender.